# ISERROR Formula Still Returns ##########

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a cell that calculates a date using a date and number from two other cells. I have 0s turned off for the sheet and I'm using the following formula to return a blank cell if there's no data to run the calculation.

```
=ISERROR(X96-W96-14,"")
```

It works fine in most of the worksheet, but once I get past rows with data in other cells it returns the result of `###############` instead of a blank which seems like an unusual format. All cells in this column are formatted the same. What have I done wrong?

[Here's a link to the file][1].  Reference the 'Assets Procurement Log' worksheet, cell F13 as an example of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dates cannot be negative and when you get to empty cells the formula will return a `-14` which when formatted as a date will return the `#########`  It is not an error that can be captured.

Instead use an IF to return a blank if either of the two cells are blank:

```
=IF(OR(X96="",W96=""),"",X96-W96-14)
```

Comment: That's awesome Scott, thanks.  It worked...mostly.  On one of my other worksheets, it works on lines where there's no data, but if there's partial data it is now returning #VALUE!.  I would've thought the OR argument would give a "" whether there's no data or partial data.  Any thoughts on this?  [link](https://batsoncookco-my.sharepoint.com/:i:/g/personal/mtraylor_batson-cook_com/EdApOj7OJ81LggtlFH7bnV0BcK9db8kd2oBJTfK6fOUUww?e=kbsi4W)

Comment: It means that one of the two is not 0 but `""` or blank.  You could try: `=IF(OR(X96={"",0},W96={"",0}),"",X96-W96-14)`

Comment: Sheer genius!  Worked like a charm.  Thanks so much Scott.